# Same script, different output under IE vs Firefox, why?

Tags: javascript

Found this piece of code somewhere:

```
function Name1(name){
    this.name = name;
}
var name = new Name1("11");
document.write(name.name);

Output:
IE11 - "11"
Firefox43 - "undefined"
```

Just interested to know why is it and what should be the correct output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're apparently running this at global scope. Global variables declared with `var` become properties of the global object.<sup>1</sup> On browsers, that object is `window`. `window` already has a property called `name`: It's the name of the window (if any). On Firefox, it can only be a string, so assigning an object to it is ignored; IE is apparently more lenient (and arguably, as of the HTML5 spec, wrong; [`name` is defined as a `DOMstring`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-window-object)). So `name = new Name1("11")` ends up being a no-op on Firefox, and `name.name` (reading the `name` property of a string) yields `undefined`.

If you change the name of the variable, you get the same output on both browsers:

```js
function Name1(name){
    this.name = name;
}
var x = new Name1("11");
console.log(x.name);
```

Conflicts like this are one of the many, many reasons to avoid running code at global scope if you can help it; wrap things in scoping functions:

```js
(function() {
    function Name1(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    var name = new Name1("11");
    console.log(name.name);
})();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In contrast, global variables declared with `let` do **not** become properties of the global object, which immediately raises the question of: What is the output of the following script with `let` on Firefox?

```js
// REQUIRES ES2015+ SUPPORT
function Name1(name){
    this.name = name;
}
let name = new Name1("11");
console.log(name.name + " (" + typeof name + ")");
```

And the answer, satisfyingly, is that it outputs "11 (object)" (so does Chrome, which also correctly outputs `undefined` for your original example), whereas the above with `var` (https://jsfiddle.net/s1j11023/) outputs "undefined (string)":

```js
// REQUIRES ES2015+ SUPPORT
function Name1(name){
    this.name = name;
}
var name = new Name1("11");
console.log(name.name + " (" + typeof name + ")");
```

Comment: Chalk this up as a reason not to run code in the global space and to always use `var` (or `let`/`const`).